# Why is my table being rendered empty?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, render

I'm writing some php that renders a table from a database, this should be simple, but for some reason, it is rendering extra cells and all cells are empty.  Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $db= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb", "user", "password");
    $query= $db->query("SELECT yarnId, yarnName, longYarnDescription, sale_price, cost, contents, onSale, yarnImage, activeFlag FROM yarn"); 
    $result= $query->fetchAll();
?>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
    <th>yarnId</th>
    <th>yarnName</th>
    <th>description</th>
    <th>sale price</th>
    <th>cost</th>
    <th>contents</th>
    <th>onSale</th>
    <th>yarnImage</th>
    <th>activeFlag</th>
    <th>edit</th>
   </tr>
   <?php for($r=0; $r<count($result); $r++){?>
    <tr>
        <?php for($c=0; $c<count($result[0]); $c++){?>
            <td><?php echo $result[r][c];?></td>
        <?php }?>
        <td><button name=edit>edit</button></td>
    </tr>
   <?php }?>
</table>
```

If anyone can tell me why it's empty and why there are extra cells, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if your login info was correct, but i've removed your login credentials and replaced them with placeholders just in case.

Comment: please print this after fectAll
var_dump($result):

Comment: What do you think you are accomplishing with nested loops? Why are you fetching the entire result set rather than displaying a line at a time from the result set (your approach could be MUCH more memory intensive depending on size of result set).

Comment: The content of the array is correct, so it's not a problem with the DB or its queries.

Comment: `<td><?php echo $result[r][c];?></td>` should be `<td><?php echo $result[$r][$c];?></td>`

Comment: Would foreach() not better suit?

Comment: Thank you maxiscool, you fixed the empty cells; however there are still extra cells being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses `while()`loop instead of `for()`

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
    <th>yarnId</th>
    <th>yarnName</th>
    <th>description</th>
    <th>sale price</th>
    <th>cost</th>
    <th>contents</th>
    <th>onSale</th>
    <th>yarnImage</th>
    <th>activeFlag</th>
    <th>edit</th>
   </tr>
<?php 
while($row = $query->fetch()) { 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    for ($x=0;$x<= 8; $x++)  {
        echo "<td>" . $row[$x] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "<td><button name=\"edit\">edit</button></td></tr>\n";
}
?>
</table>
```